# Shopify can we change and override core code?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

We have got new work for e-commerce website which is built in Shopify framework.We have a custom requirement on this website.the client wants to change the functionality of search box section in the header.Since we have not more idea about **Shopify** framework but we have worked in Ruby on Rails (Shopify built in **RoR** language) language.So my question is can we override and edit Shopify core files?if not what is the solution to make custom work in Shopify?

As in my knowledge, **Shopify** is paid framework and his team is provide extension and plugin but can we edit and update in these plugins?

If anyone has an idea please share your thoughts so that we can proceed our work.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why Downvote, let me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can not overwrite Shopify's Core framework. There is some customization that can be done through their script editor but it is only available for plus merchants.

https://help.shopify.com/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/shopify-scripts

What kind of functionality are they looking to change? Most likely you'll have to create an external application and use Shopify API's to do this or use a search app from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You can not overwrite Shopify's Code. There is some customization that can be done through their script editor.
highly restriction Admin Pages Like Dashboard, Product pages, order pages, etc...
Most likely you'll have to create an external application.